# Android Foreground Service Help

Tags: android, service, foreground

I'm working on an application that requires I run a long process in the foreground (mostly downloading a few large files), however, after much searching, and googling I have been unable to turn up a tutorial or example on foreground services. I've never used a foreground service so I'm a bit lost at the moment. Could anyone lend a hand on basic foreground services, maybe some sample code on starting one and ending one?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383300/android-foreground-service-which-can-be-bound?

Comment: don't quite get why it's closed as off-topic. It's a real programming question IMO. Instead, OP should have been recommended to provide code sample of what he tried

Comment: This question is not offtopic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is given in the developer guide over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an AsyncTask if it's running in the foreground.

With an AsyncTask you can run things in the UI on progress updated with `activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable())`

Give this a try, see if it is what you're looking for :)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Using an asynctask only, requires the app to be running. If he wants the download to proceed while the user is doing something else he'll need it in a foreground service (or maybe use the built in download service).